# Why keyboard keys aren't aligned?

Tags: keyboard, touch-typing

I am training to become a touch typist and find out that some keys, like "c", ",", "y" are very tricky to reach because they stand in a difficult angle for fingers.

So, I think there would be so much easier to touch type if keyboard keys were aligned between rows.

Why they're not?

Comment: QWERTY isn't for everyone you might try Dvorak instead however QWERTY layout is very efficient and has been around.  You might try an ergonomic also

Answer (score 2):

(This is an educated guess based on tinkering with typewriters when I was a kid)

Its generally accepted The QWERTY keyboard was laid out in such a way that keys likely to be pressed in quick succession were on different parts of the keyboard to reduce the likelihood of jamming.

I posit that the offset of keys is a similar artifact - that the keys needed to be offset so that each key (which was on an arm which struck a ribbon in a center point of the keyboard) could reach the center point.  The following picture (from Wikimedia, under CC license) shows the arrangement of keys and levers.

[image]

Note that [some ergonomic keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergonomic_keyboard) have the kind of key alignment you are referring to, but superimposed on a curved base.

Comment: Looks like the keys are aligned between rows in this layout.

Comment: This is not the case - it may appear that way to you because of the way the picture is taken.  Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Underwood_typewriter_Poland_before_1939.jpg which shows the keyboard straight on.